# Why does RStudio repeat the R startup message 4 times over when I start it?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I start RStudio, the following startup message is repeated 4 times over:

> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid" Copyright (C) 2022
> The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
> x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
> welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
> or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> Natural language support but running in an English locale
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
> 'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
> R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
> 'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
> quit R.

I assumed it might be because of my `~/.Rprofile` file but it was empty. I am at a loss to understand why this is. Is there another source file I can check?

Comment: It seems to be [a rare but known issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6907).